# Field true not found on type Site

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, graphql, entitygraphql

I'm using [EntityGraphQL](https://entitygraphql.github.io/) with an ASP.NET Core app that uses Entity Framework Core.

This query works:

```
{
  sites(filter: "id==1") {
    id
    name
    isActive
  }
}
```

But this one fails with an error:

> Field true not found on type Site

```
{
  sites(filter: "isActive==true") {
    id
    name
    isActive
  }
}
```

[The documentation says I should be able to do that](https://entitygraphql.github.io/docs/field-extensions/filtering), why is it not working?

**update**

This is the Site Model

```cs
public class Site 
    {

        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(150)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public bool IsActive { get; set; } = true;
    ...
```

I'm using:

- .NET 6
- EntityGraphQL.AspNet 5.0.0

I'm decorating the DbSet with [UseFilter]

```cs
  [UseFilter]
  public DbSet<Site>? Sites { get; set; }
```

Comment: What the .net version you are using ?  And the version of `EntityGraphQL.AspNet` ?

Answer (score 0):

If I do this, it works

```
{
  sites(filter: "isActive==(1==1)") {
    id
    name
    isActive
  }
}
```

So it must be something with the way the string "isActive==false" is parsed, so I cloned the project and I don't know anything about ANTLR or parsers, but if I delete true and false from this part of EntityQL.g4 then it works

```
// identity includes keywords too
identity: ID
    | 'true' DELETE THIS
    | 'false' DELETE THIS
    | 'and'
    | 'if'
    | 'then'
    | 'else';
```

Something else must break of course, but it might give someone a clue

[Issue Raised](https://github.com/EntityGraphQL/EntityGraphQL/issues/314)

Comment: It's glad you can find this way to fix the issue, I don't know why we follow the docs not working ...